# Barcode scanning through Salesforce mobile - 2019

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, barcode

I looked at previous questions and it seems that this [blog post from Bob Buzzard](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2014/03/reading-barcodes-in-salesforce1.html) from 2014 shows that **it's possible to scan barcodes through a VF page.**

I want to know if this is possible with recent iOS updates from Apple. Has anyone tried this recently?

Any help is greatly appreciated.